# Having error when using ssh2_connect() undefined function php 5.4.3 on windows 7 64bit

Tags: php, windows, libssh2

i'm using wampserver 2.2 apache 2.2.22 php 5.4.3 mysql 5.5.24, I've installed php_ssh2.dll extension for php 5.4 and i added it in php.ini as
`extension=php_ssh2.dll` then restarted all services. I tried to use `ssh2_connect()` but it doesn't work and I don't really understand why cause the version is compatible with php 5.4.3.

Please if you're having any tips just let me know here is the link where i downloaded 
[ssh2.dll](http://www.apachehaus.com/forum/index.php?topic=839.0)

Comment: Does phpinfo() list the extension as loaded?

Comment: Unless you provide a concrete error message, no further directions in your concrete case can (and should) be given. Which error message do you get? If you don't know, enable error logging in your php ini (to catch startup errors, this is important in your case) and follow the error log. Edit your question then and provide the missing error message. If you already solved your problem in the meanwhile, please reproduce and add the error message as well. Also please answer then your own question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I'd just recommend [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). It has [a number of advantages over what you're using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14305875/569976). Among others, it's ton more portable and easier to install.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. Please leave suggestions for alternatives in comments instead. Especially as this is another link only answer.