# SSH function doesn't exist

Tags: php, ssh

I try create user with SSH, but in website I get this error: function ssh2_connect doesn't exist. What can I do?

My all code:

```
    <?php
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
if (!($con = ssh2_connect("77.241.202.58", 22))) 
{
    echo "Klaida\n";
} 
else 
{
    if (!ssh2_auth_password($con, "root", "pass")) {
        echo "Negalima\n";
    } else {
        // allright, we're in!
        echo "Prisijungta\n";

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you on windows or linux? In any case, you will probably need to compile it yourself or download a built version (that only works for a specific version).

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation: use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). Trying to install libssh2 is quite difficult and phpseclib is often just plain better anyway:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14305875/569976

Answer (score 0):

You are missing OpenSSL or libssh2 on your server: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.requirements.php