# Using PHP to send SSH commands and print the results in a web page

Tags: php, html, mysql, ssh

I've almost completed a site that will allow Field Engineers to access certain servers we control and run certain commands via a Python script.  For the most part, the site is working and does what I need it to do.  The databases that I created on MAMP are working fine and are where I store the user's registration data.

My issue is with the page I entitled "commandspg.php" and this is where the users will enter the various commands to submit to the servers.  With Python, and a bit of Paramiko, it's necessary to use an SSH shell to send the commands and that's where I've been hitting a wall.

I've looked up just about every possible coding configuration there is to get this done and run quite a few, but none seem to give me the results I'm after. What I'd like to happen is that a user be able to use our GUI and enter the 'user', 'password', server IP address, and the command--we have a list of them on a separate page they can access--and then submit it.  This would then allow them to go to a "reportspg.php" and read and/or print the results of their command actions.

Any suggestions and/or guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Oh, and I should point out that I did have to remove a few keywords, so as not to let it be known who I'm writing this for.  Thanks!

The following is the entire page's coding content.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 body,td,th {
color: #03F;
 }
 a:link {
color: #29D93F;
 }
 body {
background-color: #DAD5D5;
 }
 </style>
 <meta 
 http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="revealTrans(Duration=3.0,Transition=23)"> 
 <meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="revealTrans(Duration=3.0,Transition=23)">
  </head>
<body>
<center>
<p><h1><strong><big>SANDBOX SERVER ACCESS PAGE</big></strong></h1></p></center>
<a href="userlogoutpg.php"><strong>LOGOUT PAGE &rarr; </strong></a><br>
<br>
<a href="commandslistpg.php"><strong>COMMANDS HELP LIST &rarr; </strong></a><br>
    <br>
<form action="commandspg.php" method="post">
   <fieldset {width: 20%; float: left; position: relative;}><legend><strong>Enter IP  
    Manually</strong></legend>
  <input type="text" name="ipaddress" value=" " size="50">       
   </fieldset>
  <fieldset {width: 20%; float: left; position: relative;}><legend><strong>User</strong>
  </legend>
 <br>
<p>
<label>
<input type="text" name="user" value=" " size="50">
</label>
</p>
</fieldset>
<fieldset {width: 20%; float: left; position: relative;}><legend>    
 <strong>Password</strong></legend>
<p>
<label>
<input type="password" name="password" value="" size="50">
</label>
</p>
</fieldset>
<fieldset {width: 20%; float: left; position: relative;}><legend>  
  <strong>command</strong></legend>
<p>
<label>
<input type="text" name="cmd" value=" " size="50">
</label>
</p>
</fieldset>
<p>
<center>
<input type="submit" input name="submit" value="  SUBMIT  "><input type="reset"  
  input name="reset" value="   CLEAR   ">
</p>
 </form>
<?php
 $ip = 'ipaddress'; 
 $user = 'user'; 
 $pass = 'password';
 $cmd = 'cmd'; 

 if(isset($_POST['submit']) ) {

  $connection = ssh2_connect($ip); 
  ssh2_auth_password($connection,$user,$pass); 
  $shell = ssh2_shell($connection,"bash");

  function __construct($host='', $port=''  ) {

 if( $host!='' ) $this->host  = $host;
 if( $port!='' ) $this->port  = $port;

 $this->con  = ssh2_connect($this->host, $this->port);
 if( !$this->con ) {
   $this->log .= "Connection failed !";
 }

 }

 function authPassword( $user = '', $password = '' ) {

 if( $user!='' ) $this->user  = $user;
 if( $password!='' ) $this->password  = $password;

 if( !ssh2_auth_password( $this->con, $this->user, $this->password ) ) {
   $this->log .= "Authorization failed !";
 }

 }

 function openShell( $shell_type = '' ) {

    if ( $shell_type != '' ) $this->shell_type = $shell_type;
 $this->shell = ssh2_shell( $this->con,  $this->shell_type );
 if( !$this->shell ) $this->log .= " Shell connection failed !";

 }

 function writeShell( $command = '' ) {

 fwrite($this->shell, $command."\n");

}

function cmdExec( ) {

    $argc = func_num_args();
    $argv = func_get_args();

 $cmd = '';
 for( $i=0; $i<$argc ; $i++) {
    if( $i != ($argc-1) ) {
      $cmd .= $argv[$i]." && ";
    }else{
      $cmd .= $argv[$i];
    }
  }
  echo $cmd;

    $stream = ssh2_exec( $this->con, $cmd );
  stream_set_blocking( $stream, true );
  return fread( $stream, 4096 );

}

function getLog() {

 return $this->log;

    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you explain what your page _currently_ does, so that people can see where it might be going wrong? Is it resulting in errors? What problem are you experiencing specifically, and at what line number?

Comment: I get a "Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sandbox1/commandspg.php on line 65" message.

Line 65 refers to the PHP code that reads-->$connection = ssh2_connect($ip);

Now, I should add that I initially hadn't installed libssh2 onto my system, but I have done this since posting this question.

Comment: What happens now? (Please be aware that if you get an error message, you should post it in your question to start with, and then if you correct something after receiving a suggestion, again you should explain what happens.) So, do you still get the same error message?

Answer (score 0):

I think [expect](http://php.net/manual/en/book.expect.php) is what you are after.

Comment: This is the result that I'm currently getting-->
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sandbox1/commandspg.php on line 65

Comment: I should add that Line 65 appears to relate to the PHP line of code that reads--> $connection = ssh2_connect($ip);

Comment: You don't have ssh2 php module installed look here for instructions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php

Comment: Okay, I went through that process and installed SSH2.

Comment: You still don't have ssh2 installed. Did you restart apache?

Answer (score 0):

Try [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

phpseclib offers a number of [advantages over the alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14305875/569976).